# java multithreading start() and run()

Tags: java, multithreading

**Below is my Multithreading class:**

```
public class Multithreading extends Thread{

    public void run(){
         for(int i=1;i<5;i++){  
             try{
                 Thread.sleep(500);
             }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }  
          System.out.println(i);  
          }  
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Multithreading t1 = new Multithreading();
        Multithreading t2 = new Multithreading();
        t1.start();
        t2.run();
    }
}
```

**And, this the output what I got:**

1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4

Could you please explain the output, I mean how this execution of start() and run() is working here.

Comment: `t2.run()` - no thread is created here. `t2` is simply an object that you run `run` method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot predicate output order in case of Threads.

```
Multithreading t1 = new Multithreading();
    Multithreading t2 = new Multithreading();
    t1.start(); // Thread is executing your run() method
    t2.run(); // It is a normal execution of run() method. No Thread is here
```